# How to serialize property as though it was a base class?

Tags: c#, json, properties, json.net, deserialization

I have a object like this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Thing<T> where T: class
{
    [JsonProperty()]
    T Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to make it serialize it so that it would give something like this, when `T` is a class with a single *value* property for example:

```
{ value: "content", error: 1 }
```

instead of this:

```
{ data: { value: "content" }, error: 1 }
```

I sadly cannot derived from the data class.

Comment: You would need a custom serialiser to do something like that, but why would you even want it in the first place? This seems like a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: @DavidG Because of legacy unchangeable code on the front end

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. For example, you could serialise it in the manner you have now, and then extract the values you need in the right format after that.

Comment: @DavidG I would love to do that believe me, but in order to do that I would need to change the code that extracts the values, which I can't.

Comment: Are you saying "deserialize" (i.e. convert JSON data to an object) when you really mean "serialize" (convert an object to JSON)?

Comment: @BrianRogers Yes, I did. How did I make that mistake I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom converter for example:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(HasValueConverter))]
public class HasValue
{
    public HasValue(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class Thing<T> where T: class
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}

class HasValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(HasValue);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new HasValue(JToken.Load(reader).Value<string>());
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[Test]
public void Deserializes()
{
    var json = "{ value: \"content\", error: 1 }";
    var thing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing<HasValue>>(json);
    Assert.AreEqual("content", thing.Data.Value);
}
```